# Remove events with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
$(function(){
    //remove keydown doSomething2
    $("body").keydown(doSomething1);
});
```

In other view I have this:

```
$(function(){
    //remove keydown doSomething1
    $("body").keydown(doSomething2);
});
```

How to do what's in the comment? With my current code, both doSomething1 and doSomething2 are called. I want do disabled the one I dont need.

Comment: I recommend keeping the event handler and add a variable that tells what do do when a key is pressed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To remove an event listener with jQuery, you can use [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/):

```
$("body").off("keydown", doSomething2);
```

Remember the [`keydown` method](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) is just a shortcut for [`.on("keydown", ...)`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

However, to "disable" them it might be easier to have only one handler that executes different things based on the current selected view, or have both of them bound and each with a short check that the right view is currently selected.

Answer (score 4):

If `doSomething2` is a **function reference**, you can use [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) (jQuery 1.7+) or [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) to remove jQuery bound event handlers:

```
$('body').off('keydown', doSomething2);

// or

$('body').unbind('keydown', doSomething2);
```

Note that execution order will be a factor. If the code to unbind the event handler is run first it will have no effect. In general, jQuery event handlers are triggered in the order they're bound, so if the first code snippet in your question is executed first, this approach won't work (you'll need to re-order it).

Answer (score 4):

try this as below using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    // this would remove keydown from body
    $("body").unbind('keydown', doSomething2);
});
```